# AngularJS - testing factories which store state/data

Tags: jasmine, mocha.js, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I am working on new version of an app using legacy API (I have no controll of what the API returns etc.. ).

On the app init I request & store some site-wide info the factory which I have called `stateFactory`. Inside the stateFactory there is `categories` property (array of objects) which is storing the `id -> category name` relation.

Inside my app template I am using a filter to extract the name of the category by id `{{ cat_id | categoryNameByIdFilter }}` which is doing a lookup in the `stateFactory.categories` and returns the category name.

**How do I write a  unit test for such functionality (jasmine, mocha, chai, anything)?**

```
// represantion of what the stateFactory looks like with some data in it
app.factory('stateFactory', ['', function(){
    return {
        categories = [
            { cat_id: 1, cat_name: "some category name" },
            { cat_id: 2, cat_name: "another category name" }
        ];
    };
}])

// categoryNameByIdFilter
app.factory('categoryNameByIdFilter', ['stateFactory', function(stateFactiry){
    return function(cat_id){

        if ( !cat_id ) return null;
        var cat_obj = _.findWhere(stateFactiry.categories, {
            id: cat_id
        });
        if ( !cat_obj ) return null;
        return cat_obj.cat_name;

    };
}]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using Jasmine and [angular's mock module](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock). You can create a mock of the `stateFactory` so that it does not hit a web service while unit testing. I have used [Sinon](http://sinonjs.org/) to create my mocks and spies. You can, then, have angular inject your mock instead of the real service. This way, the only system under test is the `categoryNameByIdFilter` and not your web service.

```
// representation of what the stateFactory looks like with some data in it
app.factory('stateFactory', ['', function ()
{
    return function ()
    {
        //This is the real stateFactory, which we are going to mock out.
    };
}]);

// categoryNameByIdFilter - The system under test in this example
app.factory('categoryNameByIdFilter', ['stateFactory', '_', function (stateFactiry, _)
{
    return function (cat_id)
    {

        if (!cat_id) return null;
        var cat_obj = _.findWhere(stateFactiry.categories, {
            id: cat_id
        });
        if (!cat_obj) return null;
        return cat_obj.cat_name;

    };
}]);
```

Given the code above, we can test `categoryNameByIdFilter` by doing this...

```
describe("categoryNameByIdFilter", function ()
{
    beforeEach(module('YOUR_APP_MODULE'));
    beforeEach(function ()
    {
        //The following line creates a mock of what we expect the state factory to return. 
        //We're mocking this because it is no the system under test, the filter is.

        //A sinon 'stub' is a spy
        mockStateFactory = sinon.stub({
            categories: [
                { id: 1, cat_name: "some category name" },
                { id: 2, cat_name: "another category name" }
            ]
        });
        module(function ($provide)
        {
            //When Angular asks for a stateFactory, give them this mock instead
            $provide.value('stateFactory', mockStateFactory);
        });
    });

    //You can inject a filter using the "inject" method below
    it("should filter by id", inject(function (categoryNameByIdFilter)
    {
        //Wrap categoryNameByIdFilter in a spy so that we can make assertions off of it.
        var spy = sinon.spy(categoryNameByIdFilter);
        var result = spy(1);
        expect(result).toEqual("some category name");
        expect(spy.calledBefore(mockStateFactory)).toBeTruthy();
        expect(spy.returned("some category name")).toBeTruthy();
        sinon.assert.calledOnce(spy);
        spy(2);//Returns something besides "some category name"
        expect(spy.alwaysReturned("some category name")).not.toBeTruthy();
        sinon.assert.calledTwice(spy);
    }));
});
```

Comment: What about the `spy`? Can this be of any use here? Still not about the concept behind `spy`

Comment: You could use a jasmine spy here. I would suggest using Sinon, though. It's a fantastic javascript mocking framework. Would you like me to redo the solution using jasmine or Sinon spies?

Comment: Yes please. That would be much appreciated. Some background story, why & how would be great as well.

Comment: I have added Sinon spies and mocks. You can now make assertions on the categoryNameByIdFilter spy to see if it behaved like you expected.

Comment: much appreciated. I heard of Sinon but never got the chance to use it. I will get through your example and hopefullu understand what is going on ;) Thx!